# Raytracer texture mapping leaving artifacts

Tags: c++, debugging, geometry, texture-mapping, raytracing

So I am trying to get OBJ loading working in my raytracer. Loading OBJs works fine, but I am having some trouble with getting the texture mapping working.

Here is an image of my result. It is supposed to be a black sphere with colored "latitude and longitude" lines, with a black spot in the middle. But it seems like every second triangle is left black. You can see the result here:

[image]

My prof said that it looks like the normals are backwards, but I don't think that is the case because the shape is still being hit - and the color of the "wrong" triangles is the color of background color of the texture (ie. black in this case).

When I load the OBJ, each vertex has a UV coord associated with it. What I do to get a UV coord when a ray hits the shape is as follows:

```
T: the triangle that was hit
hp: where on the triangle the ray hit
v1,v2,v3: the vertices of the triangle, each has a UV coord UV1, UV2, UV3

find the distance to each v[i] from hp (d1,d2,d3 respectively)
find the weight of each of these (w1 = d1/(d1+d2+d3), same for d2,d3)
find the weighted UV coord: UV1/w1 + UV2/w2 + UV3/w3

find the pixel color based on this weighted coord
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on? I can post parts of my code if you think that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have a bug in your UV coordinates computation (regardless of whether you have an additional bug with your normals).

The reason I say that is: if you have hp very close to v1 for example, you will end up having a weight w1 very close to zero, and when you compute UV1/w1, it will tend to +infinity instead of the expected value UV1.

You thus need to look at [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Interpolation_on_a_triangular_unstructured_grid)

Comment: After trying barycentric coords (built in method Vector3.Barycentric), it turns out that it gives the exact same result as the method I had before. I have an idea that could work though...

Comment: based on the pseudo code you have provided, this is the only bug that can be possibly be detected. Anything else is only random guess (flipped normals, UVs not loaded properly, order of the vertices that is not correct compared to the UV order etc...). It could also be that your use of baricentric coordinates is not correct (it cannot possibly give /exactly/ the same thing, otherwise there are other things seriously wrong, since the formulas are different)

Comment: I just realized that I am not dividing by the weight, rather I am multiplying...that probably changes a lot! My prof told me to look into bi-linear interpolation, which gives a very similar looking image (although the values are not exactly the same)

Comment: yep that makes sense. According to the image, you're likely to have the order of the vertices wrong - it's not just a matter of interpolation if you are indeed multiplying. Like the uv of vertex 0 assigned to the vertex 1 etc. (basically, if you're swapping two of the 3 vertices for half of your triangles, it seems like it will look correct)